# Google maps api, маркеры

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

По отметке чекбокса в объект-хранилище маркеров добавляю `lat` и `lng` свойства.

```
 var markers = {};


$('.place input').click(function () {

    var id = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');

    if (this.checked) {

        var lat = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-lat'));
        var lng = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-lng'));

        markers[id] = {
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng
        };

        initMap();

    } else {

        delete markers[id];

        initMap();
    }
```

Орабатывается все в функции инициализации карты

```
 function initMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap-container'), {
        zoom: 3,
        center: {lat: 0, lng: 0}
    });

    for(var prop in markers) {
        console.log(prop);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: markers[prop].lat, lng: marker[prop].lng},
            map: map
        });
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь циклом пройтись по объекту, и добавить маркеры в зависимости от наличия их в хранилище. Имею на данный момент ошибку `Cannot read property '1' of undefined`

Comment: а что в консоль выводит?

Comment: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Comment: `console.log(prop);` имел в виду, если там ошибка и вылазит - выведи в консоль `markers` вне `for in loop` и посмотри что пишет